When i choose 3rd date the date range won't be nil in swift
i use AirBnb's horizon calendar and the issue is when i click on a date out of range i cant make the selectedDateRange nil. In this date picking logic what am i missing?
.days { day in
      DayView(dayNumber: day.day, isSelected: isDaySelected(day))
        .onTapGesture {
          let dayDate = calendar.date(from: day.components)!
          if let selectedDateRange = selectedDateRange {
            if selectedDateRange.lowerBound == dayDate || selectedDateRange.upperBound == dayDate {
              self.selectedDateRange = nil
            } else {
              if selectedDateRange.contains(dayDate) {
                self.selectedDateRange = nil
              } else {
                self.selectedDateRange = min(selectedDateRange.lowerBound, dayDate)...max(selectedDateRange.upperBound, dayDate)
             
              }
            }
          } else {
            self.selectedDateRange = dayDate...dayDate
          }
        }
    }

i tried all possible if conditions but couldn't make it work.

When you select a date outside of the range you end up on this line self.selectedDateRange = min(selectedDateRange.lowerBound, dayDate)...max(selectedDateRange.upperBound, dayDate) which certainly doesn’t set the property to nil.

Ok then if i turn that full line into just self.selectedDateRange = nil would it work? I think i tried that then it doesn't add the second chosen date to the range. This line actually adds the second date to the range no?

Setting it to nil on that line makes no sense since then you set it to nil on every path in your if/else. You need to figure out how you want this to work in different scenarios. Maybe writing this using a switch statement would make it clearer.

Simple. As most of the booking apps do, i want to select 2 dates as a range but when a third one is selected inside or outside of the range , the range must be nil

Then skip all if/else conditions and always set it to nil

i think i couldn't form that cases. do you mind showing modified version for me?

I don't think the solution you want is so easy as you claim and there is also some conflict between what you write and what is in your code. I think the best thing for you is to sit down and list all possibilities on paper and what you expect should happen for each case so that you has a clear understanding of the expected behaviour, right now I doubt you have that.

for those who might come across this problem. i solved the problem with this line of switch case
case let range? where range.lowerBound != dayDate 
    && range.upperBound != dayDate 
    && !range.contains(dayDate) 
    && range.lowerBound != range.upperBound 
    || range.contains(dayDate):

this is the whole part of code
        .days { day in
            DayView(dayNumber: day.day, isSelected: 
            isDaySelected(day))
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                    var components = day.components
                    components.hour = 12 
                    
                    
                    guard let dayDate = calendar.date(from: 
                    components) else { return }
                       
                    switch selectedDateRange {
                    case nil:
                       
                        self.selectedDateRange = dayDate...dayDate

                    case let range? where range.lowerBound == 
                     dayDate || range.upperBound == dayDate:
                      selectedDateRange = nil
                        
                    case let range? where range.lowerBound != 
                     dayDate && range.upperBound != dayDate && 
                    !range.contains(dayDate) && range.lowerBound != 
                    range.upperBound || range.contains(dayDate):
                      
                        self.selectedDateRange = dayDate...dayDate

                    case let range?:
                        
                        self.selectedDateRange = 
                        min(range.lowerBound, 
                      dayDate)...max(range.upperBound, dayDate)
                    }
                }
            }


WHAT switch? Your posted code uses a complex set of nested if statements. I'm glad you found a solution, but you should post your full switch statement and explain it if you're going to post it as an answer.

as Joakim Danielson suggested above i turned all if statements into switch. let me edit my answer and show whole switch part.
